# Exception in constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, oop, exception

Lets say I have the following code

```
class B
{ /* implementation*/ };

class A
{
    B b;
    char * c;
    A() : b(), c(new char[1024])
    {}
    ~A()
    {
        delete[] c;
    }
};

int main()
{
     A* a = nullptr;
     try 
     {
          a = new A();
     }
     catch(...)
     {
         
     }
}
```

I want to understand what will happen if `c(new char[1024])` will throw exception? Will `b` correctly destroyed? Can caller catch this exception? If yes, what will be the value of `a`? Will `~A()` be called? Is it good practice to call functions in the constructor initialization list that can throw an exception?

Comment: Yes. nullptr. Its fine.

Comment: Although make c a unique_ptr, as if you added any more things which could fail c wouldn't get freed.

Comment: You can test it decorating `A` and `B` constructors and destructors and throwing an exception from `A`'s constructor: https://godbolt.org/z/e4cKEo7cj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to understand what will happen if `c(new char[1024])` will throw exception? Will `b` correctly destroyed?

Yes.  When a constructor throws, any *already*-constructed members and base classes are destructed automatically.

> Can caller catch this exception?

Yes.

> If yes, what will be the value of a?

`nullptr`, because that is what you initialized `a` with, and the exception is thrown before you can assign a new value to `a`.

> Will `~A()` be called?

No. If `A()` does not complete cleanly, the `~A()` destructor is not called. And you are not calling `delete` on any fully constructed `A` object, either.

> Is it good practice to call functions in the constructor initialization list that can throw an exception?

That is perfectly fine.  Just make sure that any *previously* constructed members are cleaned up properly to avoid any leaks.

For example:

```cpp
class A
{
    B * b;
    char * c;

    B* getB() { return new B; }
    char* getC() { return new char[1024]; }

public:
    A() : b(getB()), c(getC())
    {}

    ~A()
    {
        delete b;
        delete[] c;
    }
};
```

`b` is initialized before `c`, so if `getC()` throws then the memory that `b` is pointing at will be leaked.

You can fix that in one of two ways:

1. moving the allocations into the constructor body and using normal exception handling:

```cpp
class A
{
    B * b;
    char * c;

    B* getB() { return new B; }
    char* getC() { return new char[1024]; }

public:
    A()
    {
        b = getB();
        try
        {
            c = getC();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            delete b;
            throw;
        }
    }

    ~A()
    {
        delete b;
        delete[] c;
    }
};
```

2. using smart pointers:

```cpp
class A
{
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> c;

    std::unique_ptr<B> getB() { return std::make_unique<B>(); }
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> getC() { return std::make_unique<char[]>(1024); }

public:
    A() : b(getB()), c(getC())
    {}

    ~A() = default;
};
```

Comment: The 3rd way to fix: instead of moving the allocations into the constructor body, use "function try block".

Comment: @Eugene I thought about that, but dismissed it because when a [`function-try-block`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) is used on a constructor, the members are already gone when the `catch` is called, so it can't clean them up: "*Before any catch clauses of a function-try-block on a constructor are entered, all fully-constructed members and bases have already been destroyed... The behavior is undefined if the catch-clause of a function-try-block used on a constructor or a destructor accesses a base or a non-static member of the object.*".

Comment: @Eugene and even if that were not the case, inside the `catch` there would be no way to know which members were initialized and which were not before the exception was thrown, without possibly introducing more tracking variables.

Comment: That's a really interesting quote ... So, even though dtor of `char* c` is trivial, we cannot access `c` in `catch` of function-try-block? Then, I don't understand what this block can be useful for in ctor. And I thought catching exceptions from member-init-list of ctor is the main motivation for function-try-block.

Comment: @Eugene "*we cannot access `c` in `catch` of function-try-block?*" - correct. "*I don't understand what this block can be useful for in ctor*" - logging, custom memory pooling,etc. Just not member management. "*I thought catching exceptions from member-init-list of ctor is the main motivation for function-try-block*" - "*The **primary purpose** of function-try-blocks is to respond to an exception thrown from the member initializer list in a constructor by logging and rethrowing, modifying the exception object and rethrowing, throwing a different exception instead, or terminating the program.*"

Comment: So, can you give an example of a useful function-try-block in ctor? Or it is too long for a comment and I should ask a separate question?

Comment: @Eugene did you see the examples in the [`function-try-block` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) on cppreference.com?

Comment: Yes, that example helps. Thank you.